# Knockout Mutliple Dropdowns that adds new items

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

Is it possible for me to have multiple dropdown menus (not a specific amount)  that has Items and a New Item option that adds a new Item to the dropdown list.

For example there would be ~5 dropdowns and the user selects the Item number.  When they select New Item it adds an Item to the list

This is as far as i get with it, not sure how i can handle this problem with knockout.  Is it actually possible?

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice"></select>
<br/>
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice"></select>
<br/>
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: selectedChoice"></select>
<br/>


var Item = function(data){
var self = this;
self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
   self.items = ko.observableArray([
        new Item({id: "1", name: "Item 1"}),
        new Item({id: "2", name: "Item 2"}),
        new Item({id: "3", name: "New Item"})]);
    self.sendMe = function(){

        alert(ko.toJSON({ selectedItemId: this.selectedChoice()}));
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dqUAz/1470/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm trying to wrap my head around your example - so you want multiple dropdowns that all have a new item option in them, and when clicked adds another <select> to your page? I think it's doable, but probably a lot easier to just have an "Add new" button thats separated from the dropdowns. Is that an option?

Comment: Needs to be when New Item is selected, it will automatically add to the list. I will have multiple dropdowns, each have their own item value, so there could be two Item 1, one Item 2, maybe one Item 3.  And yes it would be possible to add extra <select> tags to the page

Comment: Should each dropdown list be self contained? As in, if I have 3 dropdowns, and I select "new item" on the second one, should the other two dropdowns also get the new item?

Comment: Thats right yeah,  so if i started with only two items, and added an extra two items, i would have the choice of 4 options throughout all of the dropdowns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way of accomplishing this would be to subscribe to the **selectedChoice** observable and update the array anytime 'New Item' is selected:

```
self.selectedChoice.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    var lastItem = self.items()[self.items().length - 1];
    if (newValue === lastItem.id()) {
        // Add the new item
        var id = self.items().length + 1;
        var name = 'Item ' + self.items().length;
        var item = new Item({id: id, name: name});
        self.items.push(item);

        // Drop and re-add the 'New Item' item so that it remains at the bottom
        self.items.remove(lastItem);
        self.items.push(lastItem);

        // Select the newly added item
        self.selectedChoice(id);
    }
});
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/dw1284/60n7078s/2/